# How to correctly parse Json from php json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, cordova

I want to parse json data created by PHP json_encode in my front end app, i can't do this:

```js
var data= '<?php echo $jsonarr; ?>';
```

As it is a Cordova app.
Here is my php code:

```
 <?php
 $arr_login= array("lname"=>"$rowlname","email"=>"$rowemail","fname"=>"$rowfname","mobile"=>"$rowmobile");
  echo json_encode($arr_login);
 ?>
```

My ajax code:

```js
   $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url: url,
   data:data,
   success: function(data){
   var res = $.trim(data);
   if (res == "Password is inccorrect" || res== "Email is inccorrect") {
    $("#errmsg").html(data);
   }
     else{
     var response= JSON.parse(data);
     alert(response);
     //window.open("dashboard.html?sess=logined&","_self");

     }
 }

     });
```

Now if I alert data it gives me the valid JSON format as sent by PHP, but I need to convert it to javascript object so I can use it in DOM but JSON.parse gives this error in the console:

```
 VM236:14 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 147
```

Comment: What does console.log(data) show you? I mean the raw response, before parsing.

Comment: can you please console.log response and share the api response?

Comment: thanks @vitkarpov this help me, the console show two of ?> that is ?> ?> I typed this twice in my PHP code  making the JSON data an invalid format. Fixed it already thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

```
var response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: wouldn't this turn it to a string?, what is needed is a javascript object. Solved the issue anyways, error was parse syntax in PHP code having double of this ?> at end of file

Answer (score 1):

Why do you alert all the json variable which is definetely an object?
I have simulated your process, as @Anik Anwar 's mention `JSON.stringify` is the solution

```
    <?php

        $rowlname = "row";
        $rowemail = "email";
        $rowfname = "rowfname";
        $rowmobile = "rowmobile";

        $arr_login= array("lname"=>"$rowlname","email"=>"$rowemail","fname"=>"$rowfname","mobile"=>"$rowmobile");
        $jsonarr = json_encode($arr_login);

    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

    <script>
        var data = '<?php echo $jsonarr ?>';
    </script>

    <script>
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                var res = $.trim(data);
                var response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                window.alert(response.lname);
            }

        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yeah, returning the object seems awkward, but i was doing this as part of debugging the error as JSON.pare() suppose to do the work, but it wasn't so i wanted to find out if actually an object is returned or not. I Just tried tried stringify it does returns the response as string, but wanted an object. Thanks

Comment: If you want it get as json object in the backend side, do not forget to specify data with contentType: 'application/json', otherwise it's content type multipart/form-data

Comment: Isn't that meant to be auto detected?. I didn't put that in backend and am using the returned response without issues. How about that?

Comment: If it is fit and not a issue in process, there is no problem. I just follow that as habbits.